# How to fix problem with loosing event tracking on inputs after redirect in reach-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reach-router

tech stack: `"@reach/router": "1.3.1"`, `"react": "16.12.0"`. I have a problem with loosing focus/loosing event tracking on text inputs in one of my components.

Example of my structure:

```
function HomeView = () => {
   return (
     <div>
        <h1>Home View</h1>
        <Link to="/document-upload-view">Add document</Link>
     </div>
   )
}

const FileComponent = ({data, setData}) => {
   return <input type="file" onChange={file => setData({...data, file: file})} />
}

const TitleComponent = ({data, setData}) => {
   return <input type="text" value={data.title} onChange={e => setData({...data, title: e.target.value)} />
}

function DocumentUploadView = ({sendFile}) => {
    const [stage, setStage] = useState(1);
    const [data, setData] = useState({title: "", file: null})
    enter code here
    function handleStageDisplay = () => {
        if(stage === 1) {
          return <FileComponent data={data} setData={setData}/>
        }
        else if (stage === 2) {
         return <TitleComponent data={data} setData={setData}/>
       }
    }

    return (
     <div>
     {handleStageDisplay()}
     <button onClick={stage === 1 ? setStage(2) : sendFile(data)}>{stage === 1 ? "Next step" : "send data"} </button>
     </div>
    )
}

function MainComponent = () => {
   return (
     <div>
        <DocumentUploadView />
        <HomeView />
     </div>
   )
}
```

So the structure looks like this: I have a main view component and two different routes: "/home" and "/document-upload-view". When I click on the Link element it redirects me to DocumentUploadView and I can fill the stage 1 input, then I can press Next and the second stage appears. I can fill the text input and send the file with imported sendFile function.

The sendFile function sends the data to the server and then after success it redirects me with navigate("/home").  It works perfect for the first time. If I want to upload the document second time, and press the `Add document` button that redirects me to the upload page something weird happen. The first stage works great, and the second stage doesn't work. Everything appears, I can point the input and write something but the event handler doesn't detect any event. I was trying to force focus the input after onClick event, and console.log(e.target) or even console.log(e)  but it doesn't show anything.

For the first time it works well, events are logging in the console. Something is happening after Redirect action. I was trying to use react-router instead of reach router but it doesn't work.

Any idea what is going on here?
Why redirect action cause this?
I'm using hooks, but I was trying to use classes with no effort.
I was checking the path of every step with someone else, and we didn't notice anything that could cause or be a part of loosing focus or loosing the ability to catch events by the input.

Comment: Update. It must be connected to the reach/router lib. Does anyone know the issue or had similar to this?